# Do pushes to docker hub always increment the "pull" count?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I've done it a few times just to make sure I hadn't missed something but every time I create a new private repository on Docker Hub and push to it, the pull count goes up by 1 even though I've never pulled from it yet. These have always been test images so far because I don't want to put anything important on here until I find out whether or not someone else is pulling my private repos.

I've never set up any webhooks on the repos. They're always brand new.

In fact, when you push to the same repo subsequent times, the pull count keeps increasing.

Is this normal behaviour? I don't get it. Does it count pushes as pulls? It doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Every push command internally has a pull command in it. That's why every push to docker hub increments the pull count.